# Create a div #map-canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

i have a page with a google map container, when click a link the map container change to slider with ajax, i need click another button to show again the map i try with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.mapCall').click(function(){
                $('#map_container').empty();
                var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
                iDiv.id = 'map-canvas';
                function refreshQuote() {
                  $("#map_container").load("mapMain.js.");
                }
                document.getElementById('map_container').appendChild(iDiv);

            });
        });
```

The div is created but not display the map

Comment: `$('#map-canvas')` will create the element for you, though I suspect the real issue is that your function `refreshQuote()` isn't getting called.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not exactly sure what the issue is, but i think its because you think refreshQuote is getting run and its not.  try this:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.mapCall').click(function(){
                $('#map_container').empty();
                var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
                iDiv.id = 'map-canvas';

                refreshQuote();

                document.getElementById('map_container').appendChild(iDiv);

            });
        });

        function refreshQuote() {
           $("#map_container").load("mapMain.js.");
        }
```